# Can't seem to get my login screen back after installing slim

Tags: login-screen, gdm

At one point I switched from GDM to slim and now I can't seem to get past the splash screen. After pressing `Esc` I can see that it is stuck on `Starting X Display Manager: Slim`. I need to get back to GDM or just figure out what it is doing.

Thoughts?

Comment: Did you remove slim and it's libraries from your computer, or has it done this since you set it to default to slim?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming GDM is still installed:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

will let you select what your default display manager is.  If it's not installed...well, install it.

It'll go into effect on reboot.

Answer (score 3):

I would drop into a command prompt - You can switch at any time by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and login. Then you can `sudo apt-get remove slim`. Once you've done so - if you already have GDM installed then just `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` otherwise run `sudo apt-get install gdm`

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F3 worked for me.   Ctrl+Alt+F2 did not.