# How to install an alternative display manager?

Tags: 10.10, display-manager

I want to replace gdm with another display manager. I did `aptitude install slim` (tried also `xdm`) and got a possibility to configure which display manager should be used. But after the reboot the display manager didn't got started. The Ubuntu-logo with the points simulating a progress goes on and on. If I press ESC, I can see, that `slim` (or `xdm`) was started, but I cannot see any login-screen. How can I use these alternative display managers?

Comment: I really never ran through this, but I guess this might be related to your problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2586/cant-seem-to-get-my-login-screen-back-after-installing-slim

Comment: I had no problem to get back to gdm, that what this question is about. But I want to successful install slim or xdm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo aptitude install slim`

SLiM saves the themes on /usr/share/slim/themes and the configuration file on /etc/slim.conf which is the one that will do all the work.

- **background.jpg**: Here goes the Image.
- **panel.png**:It ´s the login box.
- **slim.theme**: Configuration file.

We only need to modify these files and then create a new folder inside /usr/share/slim/themes and put our own files.

`sudo mkdir usr/share/slim/themes/name_of_the_folder`

Now we´ve got to tell SLiM where to look for the files, we must edit /etc/slim.conf. And look for the line that says:

> current_theme       default

and replace it with your own folder.

Comment: Ok, I tried it, but it doesn't work. :-(

Comment: edit

/etc/sysconfig/displaymanager

change it to DISPLAYMANAGER=”slim”